# Connection issues with static IPv4 adress via powerline adapter

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, powerline

since I started working form home last week, I figured out that the WIFI connection in my working room is not that good. Therefore, I thought to use powerline adapters to get a good connection from my laptop from work (lets call it Laptop A) via a ethernet wire, the two powerline adapters to the rooter

I connected and paired everything. However, the connection stopped working properly after around 3 minutes. Since it was working perfectly with another laptop (laptop B), and also the WIFI from laptop A did work without any issues near the router, I was first blaming the firewall form laptop A, since we have a more strikt policy at work.

However, I figured out that I had a static IPv4 adress the whole time (due to some integration workshop). Having the static IPv4 adress disabled, it works perfectly. 
So, I have two questions:

1. Why did the WIFI work with the static IPv4 adress?
2. Why did the static IPv4 adress led to a disruption of the internet connection via the powerline adapters?

Powerline adapter: TL-PA4010P
Router: Fritzbox 7430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is probably more appropriate on a another site because StackOverflow is mainly for programmers. Maybe in the future, you should ask this kind of question on [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

But to answer you question: Your Wi-Fi adapter and your Ethernet one are two different network interfaces for your computer. Each one will usually have different IP addresses. My guess is that your Wi-Fi was configured to get his address dynamically (which is logical since you could be connecting at many different wireless networks) but you Ethernet IP address has been set statically in the past.

That's why it was working before, because you used your Wi-Fi. Once you tried your powerline connection (which probably uses Ethernet) it wasn't configured correctly with your local network.

Comment: Right. That does make Sense.